# Adjust Date time globally

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have an ExtJS app which deals with multiple timezones. Times on the server are stored in UTC.

All dates are serialized as ISO8601 on sending to the server, so the UTC dates are correct.

This all works fine, but it happens that users have an incorrect system time. Ideally, I would like to correct this using the server time.

What I do not want to do is hack into all code that creates new Date instances to adjust the time for every new object. That would mean a lot of duplication.

Is there any way I haven't thought of to adjust the time for all Date instances, only once?

Comment: I can't see how this can be done with javascript. A solution would be to have a temporary Date object that you will assign a new value each time you need to print time. Like alert( tempDate.setTime( currentDate.getTime() + adjustment) );

Comment: @BiAiB: You can replace the native `Date` object with your own. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899675/javascript-adjust-date-time-globally/4900737#4900737).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can.  Just replace the default `Date` object with your own.  Here's a rough implementation:

```
(function() {

function adjust(d) {
     // Here's where you can make whatever adjustments you want.
     // This will be called each time a new Date object is first created.
     // This example will add an hour to every Date object.
    d.setHours(d.getHours()+1);
    return d;
}

var _Date = Date; // Hide the native Date object in our closure...

Date = function(y, M, d, h, m, s, f) { // ...and replace the global version with our own.
    var newDate;
    // Valid Date constructors:
    // Date() - current system time
    // Date(milliseconds) - milliseconds since the UNIX epoch (1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC)
    // Date(dateString)
    // Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
    switch (typeof y) {
        case 'string':
            newDate = new _Date(y);
            break;
        case 'number':
            // Unfortunately, we can't just `.apply(this, arguments)` since we're using the `new` operator.
            if (typeof M == 'number')
            if (typeof d == 'number')
            if (typeof h == 'number')
            if (typeof m == 'number')
            if (typeof s == 'number')
            if (typeof f == 'number') newDate = new _Date(y, M, d, h, m, s, f);
            else newDate = new _Date(y, M, d, h, m, s);
            else newDate = new _Date(y, M, d, h, m);
            else newDate = new _Date(y, M, d, h);
            else newDate = new _Date(y, M, d);
            else newDate = new _Date(y, M);
            else newDate = new _Date(y);
            break;
        default:
            newDate = new _Date();
    }
    return adjust(newDate);
};
Date.UTC = function(y, M, d, h, m, s, f) { throw new Error('Not implemented.'); };
Date.now = function() { return new Date(); };
Date.parse = function(d) { return  _Date.parse(d) };
})();
```

Testing:

```
console.log(new Date().toString());
console.log(new Date(1234).toString());
console.log(new Date('2011-02-04 11:00:00').toString()); // IE's date string parser won't recognize this format, but Chrome's does.  Use DateJS if necessary.
console.log(new Date(2011, 1, 4, 11, 0, 0, 0).toString());
```

...outputs:

```
Fri Feb 04 2011 13:04:29 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Wed Dec 31 1969 20:00:01 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Fri Feb 04 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
Fri Feb 04 2011 12:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

Things to consider:

- Especially since you're using large third-party libraries with who-knows-what kind of interdependencies on how `Date` works, it's likely you'll see some weirdness.  Good luck.
- Placement of this code is important.  It needs to be included **after** any code that modifies the `Date` object's `prototype` (for example, [DateJS](http://www.datejs.com/)), but **before** anything tries to instantiate a `Date`.  Anything that modifies `Date.prototype` after this executes won't work.
- I did a minimum amount of testing in Chrome and IE.  Seems to work.
- Chrome's Developer Tools normally show `Date`s as the date they represent (ie in the console and in the watch expressions), but with this active, you'll only see "Date".

Comment: Ah, this is similar to one of things I tried, a Decorator-like solution. I did not realize though that you can return the instance rather than assign values to "this". Which I should have, cause it works (and is used often) with object literals as well.

Comment: @John: Yep, as I'm sure you found out, [it is an error to assign to `this`](http://bclary.com/2004/11/07/#a-10.1.7) -- it is immutable within an execution context.

Comment: Actually NetBeans picked that one up before I even tried it. I meant assigning values (delegating methods) as members if "this". Basically delegating all method calls to a composite member, like Decorator. In any case that didn't work. I'll try your solution shortly.

Comment: This works great. I had to add the static methods from the ExtJs Date additions, but after that it worked perfectly.

http://pastie.org/1529347

Comment: Actually it should only correct the time if it's relative to the system time. But with this, I'm sure I'll be able to sort that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this with javascript. to adjust date/time of the client machine you will need to make a p/invoke call to setLocalTime or setSystemTime in kernel32.dll. to do this, you need access outside of your browser's sandbox. 
you could approach this by testing the difference for some threshold difference and ignore it if it's not too great, otherwise use the server time.

Comment: I don't think he wants to actually change the system time on client machines.  Rather, it looks like he's trying to dynamically adjust for the skew between server time and client time, which is doable (within a margin of error, obviously).